How to "cancel" a promise to make my fighting system work
I'm making a very basic clickable combat game with HTML and JavaScript. In the battles, the user starts the round, attacks, and then the enemies attack one by one.
On the player's turn, the user has to choose between two types of attacks: physical attack and magical attacks. Both types of attacks have their respective buttons. The physical attack only allows the user to deal damage to one enemy, but clicking the magical attacks button opens a menu of spells, each one with a different effect.
After choosing the attack, either physical or one of the spells, the user must select one of the enemies to execute the action. Select an enemy, and when you are sure to complete the action, you must confirm the attack by clicking the execute button.
If all goes well, the turn passes and the enemies' turn begins. An extra button was added to these functionalities: "cancel attack.". The idea is that when either of the two initial buttons (physical attack / magic attack) is clicked, this button appears, and when clicked, it allows the user action to be reset.
Here is the problem: by adding this functionality, when clicking the "cancel attack" button, the promises that are pending resolution are not canceled, but everything else is (the attack buttons reset, the selection animations for the enemies are removed, and the execute attack and cancel attack buttons disappear. Then the following happens, for example: The turn begins, I click the physical attack button, then the cancel attack button, I click the magic attack button, I select the spell that damages in area, I select the enemy I want to harm, I click the attack button and the physical attack is executed (undesirably).
This happens because when I choose an attack (specific physical/spell), a promise begins that waits for the enemy selection, and when clicking the attack execution button, it gets resolved. And the physical attack action doesn't change to the area damage spell because the promise starts before changing the type of attack and doesn't resolve until it is executed.
Here is the HTML and JS code that I have divided into two parts:
const selectedButton = document.querySelector(".selectedButton");
const backButton = document.querySelector(".actionButtons--back");

const unhiddeSelectedButton = () => {
        const selectedButton = document.querySelector(".selectedButton");
        selectedButton.style.zIndex = 1;
        selectedButton.classList.add("selectedButton--false");
}
const hiddeSelectedButton = () => {
        selectedButton.style.zIndex= -1;
}
const applySelectedClass = (evt) => {
        const enemiesHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".enemy");
        enemiesHTML.forEach(enemyHTML=>{
                if (enemyHTML.classList.contains("selected")) {
                        enemyHTML.classList.replace("selected","select");
                }
        });
        const targetEnemy = evt.currentTarget;
        targetEnemy.classList.replace("select","selected");
        selectedButton.classList.replace("selectedButton--false","selectedButton--true");
}

export const selectEnemy = () => {
        //Aparecer boton ejecutar false
        unhiddeSelectedButton();
        //Aplicar class select a todos los enemigos
        const enemiesHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".enemy");
        enemiesHTML.forEach(enemy => {
                enemy.classList.add("select");
                enemy.addEventListener("click",applySelectedClass);
        });
}

//finish select enemy
const finishSelectEnemy = () => {
        const enemiesHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".enemy");
        enemiesHTML.forEach((enemy)=>{
                (enemy.classList.contains("selected"))?enemy.classList.remove("selected"):enemy.classList.remove("select");
        });
        hiddeSelectedButton();
        backButton.setAttribute("hidden","");
}

//aplicar
const applySelected = (callback,user) => {
        
        selectedButton.classList.replace("selectedButton--true","selectedButton--false");
        let enemyHTML;
        const enemiesHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".enemy");
        enemiesHTML.forEach((enemy=>{
                (enemy.classList.contains("selected"))? enemyHTML=enemy:"";
        }))
        try {
                const i = (enemyHTML.classList.item(1)).slice(-1);
                //APLICAR ATAQUE
                callback(i,user);
                finishSelectEnemy();
        } catch (e){console.log(e)};
}

export const userAction = (callback,user) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
                selectedButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        if (selectedButton.classList.contains("selectedButton--true")) {
                                applySelected(callback,user);
                                resolve(true);
                        }
                }, { once: true });  
        });
}

more
const attackButton = document.querySelector(".actionButtons--damage");
const magicButton = document.querySelector(".actionButtons--magic");
const spellsMenu = document.querySelector(".magicAttacks-container");
const backButton = document.querySelector(".actionButtons--back");
const selectedButton = document.querySelector(".selectedButton");

//hidde users button
export const hiddenActionButtonsDiv = () => {
        attackButton.setAttribute("hidden","");
        magicButton.setAttribute("hidden","");
}
//unhidde users button
export const resetActionButtons = () => {
        attackButton.removeAttribute("hidden");
        magicButton.removeAttribute("hidden");
}
//unhidde users button + hidde back button
export const unhiddeActionButtons = () => {
        resetActionButtons();
        backButton.setAttribute("hidden","");
}
//hidde users button + unhidde back button
export const hiddeActionButtons = () => {
        attackButton.setAttribute("hidden","");
        magicButton.setAttribute("hidden","");
        backButton.removeAttribute("hidden");
}
//unhidde users spells
const openSpellsMenu = () => {
        spellsMenu.style.zIndex = 1;
}
//hidde users spells
const closeSpellsMenu = () => {
        spellsMenu.style.zIndex = -1;
}

//BACK BUTTON EVENT
const backButtonEvent = () => {

        //unhidde users button + hidde back button
        unhiddeActionButtons();
        //hidde "ejecutar" button
        (selectedButton.classList.contains("selectedButton--true"))?selectedButton.classList.replace("selectedButton--true","selectedButton--false"):"";
        selectedButton.style.zIndex=-1;

        //delete selected and select classes
        const enemiesHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".enemy");
        enemiesHTML.forEach(enemy=>{
                (enemy.classList.contains("selected"))?enemy.classList.remove("selected"):enemy.classList.remove("select");
        });

        //hidde users spells
        (spellsMenu.style.zIndex == 1)?closeSpellsMenu():"";

        //Creo que le faltaria borrar la seleccion del spell
}
backButton.addEventListener("click",backButtonEvent);

//Detect lvl & mana available spells
const detectAvailablesSpells = (user) => {
        const spellsHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".magicAttack");
        for (let i in spellsArry) {
                spellsArry[i].calculateManaCost(user);
                spellsArry[i].calculateDamageEvolution(user);
                if (spellsArry[i].manaCost>user.mana) {
                        spellsHTML[i].classList.add("disabled-spell");
                } else {
                        try {
                                spellsHTML[i].classList.remove("disabled-spell");
                        } catch (e) {
                                console.log(e);
                        }
                }
        }
}

//Select spell
const selectSpell = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
                
                const spells = document.querySelectorAll(".magicAttack");
                spells.forEach(spell=>{
                        const handleClick = (e) => {
                                const selectedSpell = e.currentTarget;
                                const spellI = selectedSpell.classList.item(1).slice(-1);
                                closeSpellsMenu();
                                resolve(spellI);
                                spell.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
                        };
                        if (!(spell.classList.contains("disabled-spell"))) {
                                spell.addEventListener("click", handleClick, {once:true});
                        }    
                })
        })

}

export const userTurn = (user,loseTurn) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
                //LOSE USER TURN
                if (loseTurn) {
                        console.log("Turno perdido debido a congelamiento");
                        resolve(true);
                        return;
                }
                //Aparecer los botones
                resetActionButtons();

                //items from inv
                const useItemSlot7 = document.getElementById("useSlot7");
                const useItemSlot8 = document.getElementById("useSlot8");
                useItemSlot7.addEventListener("click",()=>ItemsButton.useItemButton(7, user));
                useItemSlot8.addEventListener("click",()=>ItemsButton.useItemButton(8, user));


                //physical attack
                const attackButtonEvent = async() => {
                        //Desaparecer botones de atacar
                        hiddeActionButtons();
                        selectEnemy();
                        await userAction(simpleAttack,user);
                        resolve(true);
                        hiddenActionButtonsDiv();
                        attackButton.removeEventListener("click",attackButtonEvent);
                        magicButton.removeEventListener("click",magicButtonEvent);
                } 
                attackButton.addEventListener("click",attackButtonEvent);
                
                //magic attack
                const magicButtonEvent = async () => {
                        detectAvailablesSpells(user);
                        hiddeActionButtons();
                        openSpellsMenu();
                        const spellI = await selectSpell();
                        hiddeActionButtons();
                        selectEnemy();
                        await userAction(spellsEffects[spellI],user);
                        resetActionButtons();
                        resolve(true);
                        hiddenActionButtonsDiv();
                        magicButton.removeEventListener("click",magicButtonEvent);
                        attackButton.removeEventListener("click",attackButtonEvent);
                }     
                magicButton.addEventListener("click",magicButtonEvent);
                
                
        });
};


This just looks like an unnecessary use of promises. If you stored a "pending action" object, to later call "execute" on, and then nulled that object when you want to cancel, none of the unwanted behaviour would happen. Is there a reason you need to use a promise here at all?

Thank you very much for the idea! I solved it by creating an object that stores and overwrites the attack type. Sorry for the mess in the post, I will learn to make it clearer in the next one! Thank you!

Nice work. Want to share your solution as an Answer below to help future readers struggling with similar challenges?
